# MATLAB how to optimize code with macro

Tags: matlab

```
if ispc
bc = fullfile(tmp,'toto');
else 
bc = fullfile(tmp,'tata');
end
```

Is there a way to optimize this code by using macro for examples ? I didn't find somthing in documentation

Thanks,

Comment: AFAIK Matlab does not have macros. what is so wrong with this code that needs optimization?

Comment: I just want to make it as for C by using macro to avoid to repeat instruction...

Comment: Hi @lola you have multiple of your questions still open without an accepted answer, but it seems they are solved.When a answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function:

```
function bc = getBCFromTmpByPlatform(tmp)
    if ispc
        bc = fullfile(tmp,'toto');
    else 
        bc = fullfile(tmp,'tata');
    end
end
```

and then just call your function wherever you would have called your original code.